# chrome console show password with digest authentication

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, digest-authentication

I'm building an API using Digest Authentication (CakePHP). I'm using jQuery as client and its "username + password" options fields.
While everything is working pretty well, I have noticed a really strange behavior with Chrome browser's console.

In the "Headers" section, the Request URL show my password in plain text (paste from the console): `Request URL : http://my_username:my_password@project_api.dev/groups/`

I'm afraid ! Is this normal ? Will everyone being able to see my password if opening their console and sniffing request ?

I thought Digest Authentification was fairly secure since the password is encapsulated with a hash into the "response" key in "Authorization" header. I've check with Safari console and Firefox console, doesn't seem to be shown in Request URL there...

Everyone an idea why it's shown in Chrome browser ? Is it safe or not ?

Thanks !

Comment: The whole purpose of Digest authentication is to avoid having to send the password thru the wire so this makes no sense at all whenever you use https or not. This defeats the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the protocol `https` it's safe because you contact the server first to get his certificate then each transaction will be encrypted and by extension the URL too.

But you **must** use the `https`protocol for that. You can find other information about the protocol [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Protocol_details).

Comment: OK thanks ! It's gonna be in https once in production anyway. I was just wondering why Chrome show the password inside the Request URL, while Safari and Firefox doesn't.... Thanks !